# Sumar cantidades de dos tablas

Tags: sql

Quiero sumar las cantidades parciales (de la tabla Action) con la cantidad general (de la tabla Move), estas cantidades estan en dos tablas, se puede lograr?:

> La tabla Move tiene id, name, y la cantidad general(inicia con un valor por
>   defecto)
>
> La tabla Action tiene id, type, y cantidades parciales

```
SELECT SUM(m.cantidad) FROM Move m INNER JOIN Action a ON a.id = m.idA
```

Quiero ir sumando o restando (segun el type de la tabla Action) las cantidades parciales e ir modificando la cantidad general(que tiene un valor inicial)

si el type es 0 entonces se suma, de lo contrario se resta, la suma total deberia ser la nueva cantidad general

Comment: quiero ir sumando las cantidades parciales e ir modificando la cantidad general(que tiene un valor inicial)

Comment: Lo que he entendido: Quieres sumar la columna "cantidades parciales" y la columna cantidad general. Pero están en otras tablas. No?

Comment: @matahombres asi es, la suma total deberia ser la nueva cantidad general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La suma por id:

```
select v.id, sum(v.cantidad) as cantidad
from 
(
    select id as id, sum(cantidad) as cantidad 
    from "move"
    group by id
    union
    select id, 
    sum(case when type=0 then cantidad else cantidad*(-1) end)
    from "action"
    group by id
) v
group by v.id
```

La suma total:

```
select sum(v.cantidad) as cantidad
from 
(
    select id as id, sum(cantidad) as cantidad 
    from "move"
    group by id
    union
    select id, 
    sum(case when type=0 then cantidad else cantidad*(-1) end)
    from "action"
    group by id
) v
```

Hice las pruebas con Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: @HarwinEdilPerezSalinal me sale este error SELECTs to the left and right of UNION do not have the same number of result columns

Comment: @because. Edite mi respuestas adicionando una imagen de los resultados de las consultas en las pruebas que hice con MS SQL server2008R2.